# Query for get column number in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to know how can I get column number of a table in `PostgreSql`? For example, If we have a table with id, name, age columns, the age column number is 2. I can do this with array and loop in C++(using [libpqxx](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/)). But I want to know is there a better way to get this with simple and direct query?

Comment: Why would you ever need this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select      ordinal_position

from        information_schema.columns

where       table_catalog = 'my_table_catalog'
        and table_schema  = 'my_table_schema'
        and table_name    = 'my_table_name'
        and column_name   = 'my_column_name'
```

Comment: We are in 2020, pg v12... No modern function analog to `pg_get_serial_sequence()`??